# Android Stringblock.get NullPointer Exception on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, layout-inflater

I am getting a crash on Android Lolipop.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.content.res.StringBlock.get(int)' on a null object reference   
at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:213) 
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1334)  
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1323)  
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2796) 
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1143) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
```

Generally happens while inflating a view.
Any suggestions why it happens on Lollipop only ?

Comment: Excuse me, but this is not a duplicate just because the exception is `NullPointerException`. This is a crash happening only in a specific Android version, with a stack trace mentioning only framework classes, therefore a developer cannot simply check for a null variable. Any possible workaround provided in an answer would be specific to this case, and not in `NullPointerException` crashes in general.

Comment: I'm also getting this type of crash in lollipop.

Comment: Can you post the layout xml file which is causing this error?

Comment: give the code, as 99% u not initialize something and then NPE

Answer (score 7):

It is may be because of an attribute is null.

For example `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` may be null, try to use `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`.

Comment: can you share your reference or link for this? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it occurred when I was setting a image to notification from service . I remove the relevant code and it started working fine